# I hit a weird issue running a query against a PostgreSQL Database using NOT IN and don't understand why it didn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, notin

I have a hierarchical table with an id and parent_id column, the parent_id has a foreign key to the id column. Each row can only have one parent, but multiple rows can be tied to the same parent. I wanted to retrieve all the rows that didn't have any children.

I attempted this with the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id)
    FROM table
)
```

**This returned 0 rows.** If i change the **NOT IN** to **IN** it correctly returns the rows that have children (other rows tie to it through their parent_id)

I ended up getting this working:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN(
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id)
        FROM table
    )
)
```

But I don't understand why the first query didn't work? Can anybody help me to understand what's going on here? Do I not understand how **NOT IN** should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id)
    FROM table
    WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
)
```

For example:

```
with t(x) as (values(1),(2))
select 3
where 3 not in (select x from t);

┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│        3 │
└──────────┘
```

but

```
with t(x) as (values(1),(2),(null))
select 3
where 3 not in (select x from t);

┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
└──────────┘
```

It is because the DBMS can't made decision is `id = null` or not (the result is `undefined`)

You could to fix it as mentioned above or using `not exists`:

```
with t(x) as (values(1),(2),(null))
select 3
where not exists (select x from t where x = 3);

┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│        3 │
└──────────┘
```